# Unexpected page refresh after callback function

Tags: jquery, callback

Does anyone have any idea why the following callback doesn't execute the code within? I have a `window.onload` script (the only one) in my main `.html` page which is called, for some reason, immediately after the `fadeTo`.

```
$("#newentryform").fadeTo("fast", .25, function () {
    var newentry = prompt("Please enter a new item:", "");
    if ((newentry != null) && (newentry != "")) {
        var verify = confirm("Press 'OK' to confirm you wish to create a new entry:" + "\n" + newentry);
        if (verify == true) {
            processnewentry(newentry, dropid);
        }
    }
});
```

The above function is called from an `onclick` event in the main `.HTML` page.

EDIT--code requested in comments

This is the HTML around the button and onclick in question.  The call is to the makenewitem function
which is the function above.

```
<div id="entryinput">
<p>Item<input type="text" id="createitem" readonly /><button  id="createitembutton"onClick="showbuttons(this.id)">Select...</button><button id="createnewitembutton" onClick="makenewitem(this.id)">+ New</button><button id="itemReset" onClick="resetbuttons(this.id)">Reset</button>
<input type="text" id="createitemval" style="display:none" readonly/>
<input type="text" id="createitemindex" style="display:none" readonly/>
</p>
</div>
```

This is the processnewentry function:

function processnewentry (newentryvalue, dropid)
{

```
if (dropid=="createnewitembutton")
{
    dropid="createitem";
}

    else
{
          dropid="olditem";
}

var createnewItm=document.getElementById(dropid);
    createnewItm.value=newitemvalue;
var createnewitemval=document.getElementById(dropid+"val");
    createnewitemval.value="";
var createnewitemindex=document.getElementById(dropid+"index");
    createnewitemindex.value="1";


        $("#newitemform").fadeTo("fast", 1);

        var currentPage="newitembuttonpressed";
        toggleStatus(currentPage);  //disable inputs and buttons in form


    var hidebutton=document.getElementById(dropid+"button").style.display="none";
    var subdropid=dropid.substr(6);
    var hidenewbutton=document.getElementById("createnew"+subdropid+"button").style.display="none";
    var displaycreateinput=document.getElementById(dropid).style.display="inline";
```

}

Comment: structure of `processnewentry` is neede to debug your problem

Comment: TIP : write `else { return false; }` with `if(verify){}`

Comment: The answer to this question will require wild guesses until the rest of the relevant code is disclosed.  That includes the click handler, the HTML associated with the click handler (and around it) and the processnewentry function.  There simply isn't enough info here yet to do anything but make guesses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your onclick is placed on a submit button or an a tag, that might have something to do with it.

You should add return false to your button onclick calls, like this:

```
<button [...] onClick="showbuttons(this.id); return false;" />
```

This prevents the default button action (which is submit) to occur.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The onclick is on a button element, so your point is well taken.  I have tried to return false but must be placing it in the wrong spot as it doesn't seem to help.  The code within the callback just won't execute at all before it reloads the main page.

Comment: I added an example of return false to my answer. Does this help?

Comment: Also, on a sidenote, adding return false to your callback won't do anything, since clicking a button will immediately trigger a reload. So the fadeTo function will (almost) never have time to finish, and therefor will not be able to call the callback function you provided.

Comment: Yes!  Perfectly!  I learned something valuable, and you solved my problem.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `return false;` at the end of you method.